# An alternative proof of normal subgroup test

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, normal-subgroups

We call a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ normal if and only if $gH = Hg$ for all $g \in G$.

The normal subgroup test is the following theorem:

> A subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is normal in $G$ if and only if $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$ for all $g \in G$.

The proof for $\implies$ given in the book is the following:

If $H$ is normal in $G$ then for any $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ there is $h'$ in $H$ such that $gh = h' g$. Thus $ghg^{-1} = h'$ and therefore $gHg^{-1}\subseteq H$.

I tried to prove this and I wrote this proof:

If $H$ is normal then $gH = Hg$. Multiplying by $g^{-1}$ on both sides yields $gHg^{-1} = H$ hence in particular, $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$.

Now I'm wondering whether this is a false proof because it is shorter than what they do in the book and therefore would be my first choice.

> Is my proof false?

Comment: I think your proof is correct though someone could deduce that you understand $\;gH=Hg\;$ pointwise, which it is not and the book's proof makes this clear.

Comment: @Joanpemo Thank you for your comment.